# How to dynamically assign an unknown number of list elements?

Tags: python, list

I have this code which works but it's a big function block of IF..ELIF..ELSE. Is there a way to unpack or dynamically assign two lists. The thing is, sometimes `mylist` could have less elements than 4.

**Input:**

```
mylist=['1','2','3','4']
flag=['a','b','c','d']
```

**Output:**
A string object like `'a=1/b=2/c=3/d=4/'` OR `'a=1/b=2/c=3/'` if `mylist` only has 3 elements.

My current method is just like:

```
def myoutput(mylist, flag):
    if flag=='3':
        out = f'a={mylist[0]}/b={mylist[1]}/c={mylist[2]}/'
    else:
        out = f'a={mylist[0]}/b={mylist[1]}/c={mylist[2]}/d={mylist[3]}/'
    return out
```

I tried to zip the two list, but I do not know the next steps and it doesn't really work:

```
tag_vars={}
for i in range((zip(mylist,flag))):
    tag_vars[f"mylist{i}"] = flag[i]

print(tag_vars)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `zip` for this task following way

```
mylist=['1','2','3','4']
flag=['a','b','c','d']
out = ''.join(f'{f}={m}/' for f,m in zip(flag,mylist))
print(out)
```

output

```
a=1/b=2/c=3/d=4/
```

Note that I used f,m with zip so f and m are corresponding elements from flag and mylist. **Disclaimer**: this solution assumes flag and mylist have always equal lengths.

Comment: It works if one list is shorter too. It's `zip_shortest`

Comment: *"assumes flag and mylist have always equal lengths"* — It actually stops at the shorter list, which is fine, as any other behaviour is undefined in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` like this:

```
for a, b in zip(alist, blist): ...
```

I modified `myoutput` function to return your desired output

```
mylist=['1','2','3','4']
flag=['a','b','c','d']

def myoutput(mylist, flag):
    result = []
    for elem, f in zip(mylist, flag):
        result.append(f"{f}={elem}")
    return "/".join(result)

print(myoutput(mylist, flag)) # a=1/b=2/c=3/d=4
print(myoutput(mylist[:3], flag)) # a=1/b=2/c=3
```